# Google Maps API gives me net::ERR_ABORTED 400

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xhtml

I have being trying to you the google maps api (Maps Javascript API). First I made a simple html file and made a simple map, it worked. Then I made a more complicated one with marks and polylines, it worked.

With this done I decided to move it into my web application, the thing is that my application works with xhtml, not html. Still it should work. But it is not the case.

I have read many forums, but I cannot seem to find the solution to my problem. Here is the simple map code that I tryied in an html file:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Test</title>
    <style>
        #map {
        height: 100%;
        }

        html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI&callback=initialize">
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is the same information but in my .xhtml file: (my xhtml is over a template that's why it does not have any of the head information.)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<p:dialog  header="#{msg['MAP']}" footer="#{msg['TOURSYS.FOOTER.TITLE']} | #{msg['TOURSYS.FOOTER.VERSION']} | #{msg['TOURSYS.FOOTER.LAST.MODIFICATION.DATE']}" widgetVar="mapDialog" modal="true"  height="auto" width="auto">
    <h:form id="mapForm">
        <html>
            <style>
                #map {
                    height: 100%;
                }

                html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
            </style>
            <body>
                <div id="map"></div>

                <script>
                    function initialize() {
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                            zoom: 8
                        });
                    }

                </script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI&amp;callback=initialize;"/>

            </body>
        </html>      
    </h:form>           
</p:dialog>
```

The following error is popping in my google console:

> GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI&callback=initialize; net::ERR_ABORTED 400

My application is running in a maven proyect with Primefaces 6.2.7

Answer (score 1):

Theres a semicolon (;) included in the src of your JS call.

Your call :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI&amp;callback=initialize;"/>
```

It should be like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI&amp;callback=initialize"/>
```

Try it on this fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/f74p69gz/